H2 fails to create table for JPA entity
I have been writing unit tests for my company's application backend. Most of the functionality of the backend is CRUD operations on the database so I configured my tests to use an EntityManager connected to an H2 in-memory database. So far I have been able to interact with the database as I would expect, but upon persisting a particular entity class I have gotten the following error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "my_class" not found. Here is my test method (class name changed to avoid sharing company code):
@Test
public void temp() {
    MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(myObj);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

My persistence unit in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml looks like this:
<persistence-unit name="com.mycompany.test.h2">
    <description>AVM Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:avm_test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init_test_H2.sql';DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="mycompany"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

I added the ;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false bit after seeing this answer. The "my_class" went from being all caps in the error to matching how it is declared on the class, but otherwise this didn't solve the problem.
The ;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init_test_H2.sql' bit is because for some reason H2 doesn't create the schemas, so I have to have a script to create them before H2 starts creating tables.
The MyClass entity is declared with @Entity @Table(name="my_class" before it. The class also implements Serializable. I'm not sure why it implements Serializable but several other entity classes which don't have a problem also do. Otherwise I've looked over the class and can't see anything that would cause H2 to have a problem with it. It's in the same package as the rest of the entities so I don't see any reason why H2 wouldn't find it.
I have created a minimal reproducible example by removing almost every file of the project except for the test, one class which works, and one which doesn't. I uploaded a zip of the project here

Does your init_test_H2.sql contain a my_class table? Do you have a different META-INF/persistence.xml in src/test/resources?

@dan1st The init_test_H2.sql file only has create schemas. The other tables are all created automatically just fine without needing to create them in the script.
I don't have a separate persistence.xml file, I just declare the persistence unit separately in the same file. This is why.

Can you show the entity class relating to my_class?

@dan1st I can't paste company code but it's just a pojo. It has the annotations mentioned in the question: @Entity @Table(name="my_class"), some private fields annotated with @Column(name="column_name"), a no args constructor and several other constructors, and getters and setters. It also has a method @Transient public MyClassDTO toDTO().

Is there any reason you are using PostgreSQL95Dialect for H2?

@dan1st I don't remember, I don't think so. I think I just couldn't figure out which one to use or something.

Can you please reduce your code down to a [mcve].containing only what's necessary to reproduce the issue (so it's fine with your company)?

@dan1st https://pixeldrain.com/u/emw6tapy
Open folder in intellij. Run the test in src/test/java/Tests.java
